# Angular2 print text passed in ngModel instead of it's value

Tags: angular

In Angular2, If we need name of passed model instead of value how we can achieve this ?

For example

```
@Input() field: any;

<one-line [title]="'Last Name'" [(field)]="doc.lastName"></one-line>
```

My requirement is to have "doc.lastName" (anything which passed in field) not the value of doc.lastName

We can easily do in Angular1

```
scope:{
   field: '='
   fieldName: '@field'
}
```

Comment: Totally unclear to me what this question is about. I don't know Angular1 though. Could you provide a concrete example. When `field` has the value x I want to get value y assigned to z. `@Input() field` is in the parent or child component, or somewhere else?

Comment: You mean to say `field` should have static value called `doc.lastName` or value contained by `doc.lastName`. Unclear question though.

Comment: @micronyks I need both, In angular one I can have 

`scope: {
    field: '=',
    fieldName: '@field'
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a string value to an input, simply remove the `[(...])`:

```
<one-line [title]="'Last Name'" field="doc.lastName"></one-line>
```

In the OneLineComponent, the value of the `field` property will be `'doc.lastName'` in this case.

You can also notice that `[title]="'Last Name'"` is similar to `title="Last Name"`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware about this. But I need it without typing two 
`<one-line [title]="'Last Name'" field="doc.lastName" fieldName="doc.lastName"></one-line>`

In angular 1 we can easily do 
`scope: { field: '=', fieldName: '@field' }`

Comment: In A1 you have been given such flexibility to do what you have shown. But in A2 I wonder it is possible just with one name.